# writing pseudocode for my algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have implemented counting sort and I am struggling to write pseudocode for the last step of my algorithm.

My code is as follows:

```
public int[] countingSort(int[]array) {

    int[] aux = new int[array.length];

    // find the smallest and the largest value
    int min = array[0];
    int max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) min = array[i];
        else if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
    }

    // init array of frequencies
    int[] counts = new int[max - min + 1];

    // init the frequencies
    for (int i = 0;  i < array.length; i++) {
        counts[array[i] - min]++;
    }

    // recalculate the array - create the array of occurences
    counts[0]--;
    for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
        counts[i] = counts[i] + counts[i-1];
    }

    // Sort the array right to the left
    // 1) look up in the array of occurences the last occurence of the given value
    // 2) place it into the sorted array
    // 3) decrement the index of the last occurence of the given value
    // 4) continue with the previous value of the input array (goto: 1), terminate if all values were already sorted
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        aux[counts[array[i] - min]--] = array[i];
    }

    return aux;
}
```

My psuedocode is as follows:

Procedure: Counting Sort

Input: Array (A)
Steps:

Work out the min and max in the arrray

- DECLARE MIN AS first element in A
- DECLARE MAX AS MIN
- LOOP through elements in A

  - IF the current element is less than MIN

    - SET MIN to current element
  - ELSE IF the current element is greater than MAX

    - SET MAX to current element
- Initialise the array of frequencies
- DECLARE array C (counts) of size (MAX - MIN + 1)
- COUNT the frequency of each element
- LOOP through elements in A

  - C[array[i]-min] increase by 1
- Recalculate the array - Create the array of occurences
- Decrement C[0] by 1
- LOOP through elements in C

  - C[i] = C[i] - C[i-1]
- Sorting the arrays
- Look up in the array of occurences the last occurence of the given value
- LOOP through elements in the array of occurences
- Place it into the sorted array
- Decrement the index of the last occurence of the given value
- Continue with the previous value of the input array (goto: 1), terminate if all values were already sorted

Comment: Writing pseudocode shouldn't be difficult unless you don't understand the code you have written.

Comment: my question is first of all am I doing it correctly? and second of all I dont know how represent the last bit which is the sorting arrays

Comment: There is markup, to indent a list of elements. Try it out, and improve your text.